# Office 365 Home - without the monthly paper invoices

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

I like the new Office 365 subscription, and I want to subscribe.
But every time I gave it a try (one month each), I received a paper invoice a few weeks/days later.

Is there a way I could subscribe without receiving these invoices by post?
**Basically I just want my bill sent out in an email, and that's  it.**

Ps.: I don't want to send them out to some random address as it contains my personal data, nor I want to subscribe yearly/buy the boxed version.

Comment: I don’t receive any paper invoices here in Germany. I didn’t do anything special while signing up.

Comment: I think that is a question to be answered by Microsoft ...